D365 Form Customizations Not Included in Solution
We use D365 CRM.
We have a Prod environment (live) and a Staging environment (dev and testing).
In the Appointment entity in our Staging environment, I modified one of the default forms. When I try to copy that form into our Prod environment via a solution, the form edits are not being imported.
What I did:

Edited the "Wizard" form in the Appointment entity in the Staging environment
Created a solution that included the Wizard form in our Staging environment
Imported that solution into our Prod environment

Results:

The new fields that were included in that form were created in the Appointment table in our Prod environment
The edits to the form did not show up in the Prod environment


A few things to check:

Did you import a managed solution to PROD?
Did you Publish All customizations on PROD after the import solution?


Yes, the solution is managed.
Yes, I published all customizations in Prod.
The odd thing is, in prod when I look at the contents of the solution, there is no form included in that solution.
Thanks for responding!

Strange.  Are you sure the form is in the solution in Staging?
